# Persisting state to files in onPause() takes too long

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, persistence

Consider the following situation. I have an application which holds a large amount of data that is persisted into files. I spawn an AsyncTask in the onPause method for this purpose.

The problem is that it takes quite a long time. It might be the case that the user closes the activity and then starts it again, however, the files are not fully saved to disk before the activity is created again. For this reason, on the next launch, the activity contains incorrect data. How can I deal with this issue, i.e. ensure that the data is fully saved to disk before the next launch?

Comment: What are you saving in these files? Why not use a Database?

Comment: I use gson, which is useful because the files will be exported later. In the case of the database, isn't there the same problem (it might take too long)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check whether your data already stored or not. Obviously, custom flag, 'touched' files, etc.
Make your UI logic more easer to avoid this problem.

Comment: Assuming I use a touched file, how could I ensure resilience against possible problems such as: my app is killed when saving files, there is a problem with permissions and I can't touch a file, etc? In other words, how can I distinguish between a situation where I'm waiting for the file to be touched and a situation where an error occurred?

Also, what to do when I open the app and I'm still waiting for the file to be touched? Display a progress bar and check in some fixed intervals?

Comment: In my practice I use foreground services and start_sticky flag

Comment: @AlexSee,  i mean in my code huge work is not executed inside activity but service